# The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Tags: jsp, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm trying to create a form and post the answers using two .jsp pages. But I cannot access the first .jsp page, let alone the second. The error that is showing on my console is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [student] in context with path [/hibernate] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [48] in the generated java file: [E:\TechFlakes\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\hibernate\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsps\student_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [48] in the generated java file: [E:\TechFlakes\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\hibernate\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsps\student_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:986)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:933)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my Controller class:

```
package com.sazzad.bhai.database;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class ControllerClass {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showHello(ModelAndView model) {
        System.out.println("This is showHello method.");
        model.setViewName("student");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newStudent")
    public ModelAndView showNew(ModelAndView model) {
        System.out.println("This is showNew method.");
        model.setViewName("newStudent");
        return model;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String form(@ModelAttribute("StudentModel") Student student,
            ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("Inside form");
        model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
        model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());
        // model.addAttribute("student", student);
        return "main";
    }



}
```

This is my POJO file:

```
package com.sazzad.bhai.database;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This is student.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>

<html>
<head>
<title>This is student.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Student Information</h2>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/hibernate/main">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">id</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is main.jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Using GET and POST Method to Read Form Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>${name}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>${id}</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>${age}</td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

This is student-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sazzad.bhai.database"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        id="jspViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="NewPersistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sazzad.bhai.database" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="admin"/>
        <property name="password" value="admin"/>
        <!--<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>-->
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

This is web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SazzadBhai</display-name>
<!--   <welcome-file-list> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file> -->
<!--     <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> -->
<!--   </welcome-file-list> -->

    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>student</display-name>
    <servlet-name>student</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>student</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SazzadBhai</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
<!--        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--             <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId> -->
<!--             <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId> -->
<!--             <version>2.1</version> -->
<!--             <scope>provided</scope> -->
<!--         </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>log4j</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.2.15</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm unable to detect the problem in my code, will be really grateful if you help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code has worked. The changes I made are:

1. I changed the version of my javax-servlet-api from 2.3 to 3.1
2. I changed the showHello method of my Controller Class to this:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView showHello(Model model) {
       System.out.println("This is showHello method.");
       return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }
   ```

Basically, what I did is, I changed the argument of the method from ModelAndView to Model.

Answer (score 1):

Your servlet-api version is too old. You should be using 3.X or greater. As can be seen [here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/library/version/dependencies?name=org.springframework.spring&version=3.1.1.RELEASE) even releases back it was referring to 3.X.